# Pandas, convert datetime format mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in 2 different columns CSV

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I'm a beginner in python and i'm trying to convert date from YYYY-mm-dd to dd/mm/YYYY in two different dataframes/columns (StartDate and EndDate) but i'm getting the below error when converting the second column df['StartDate'] even though it works on the first column df['EndDate'].

The Current date on the file is **20220826 and i want 26/08/2022**

**ValueError: time data '26/08/2022' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)**

This is my code:

```
 df=pd.read_csv("AllNewFile.csv")
    df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df['EndDate'] = df['EndDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    df.head(10) 
    df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df['StartDate'] = df['StartDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Please assist and thank you

Comment: BTW, you are mixing up your EndDate and StartDate stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error means not all values in column `EndDate` are in format `YYYYMMDD`:

```
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

If all values are in `YYYYMMDD` and some not match format try:

```
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

Or:

```
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])
```

Comment: Thank you but this works fine. But when i do the same for df['StartDate'] i'm getting the error

Comment: @Lone-Learner Well, obviously the naswer can be applied to `StartDate` as well.

Comment: @Lone-Learner - Is possible mixed formats `YYYYMMDD` and `DD/MM/YYYY` ?